# In-Container testing with JUnit

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, junit, integration-testing

I am new to JUnit and trying to implement it in a legacy project. It is a Java EE project. Its UI layer is in Flex and the backend has Hibernate as the ORM layer with a SQL Server Database. It runs on Tomcat.

I am taking baby steps to learn JUnit myself and implement it into the codebase. There is a class which has its `findByFK` method. This method returns an array of class objects if any are found.

The method runs fine on a web application but I can't run its JUnit test case. The test case is out of the container and doesn't have access to a datasource.

How can I run a JUnit test case inside a container?

I have just started with JUnit and don't want to overcomplicate it with integration issues. Is there any way to work it out without getting into stubbing the datasource and web server etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Arquillian tests](http://arquillian.org/) allow  you to run your unit test inside your container.

Doing something like :

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class Test {
    @Test
    public void test(){
    //your test
    }
}
```

will allow you to deploy your test in your container, giving it access to your database.

Comment: Which container are you using btw?

Comment: Is it this easy to implement?

Comment: I only know it with JBoss AS7 but I think it should be working with tomcat (http://arquillian.org/blog/tags/tomcat/) Which version of J2EE are you using? It is in general quite easy to use. You only need to annotate your test using the `@RunWith` annotation and set up the deployment package (basically saying which class should be deployed in the test but this is explained in every tutorial)

Comment: Great! Application not heavy on J2EE much. It has ORM layer in hibernate and runs on tomcat server.

Comment: Do you know how to configure Arquillian for tomacat 6 managed datasources? I have checked all its documentation but no help.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav I think this link can be helpful for a start- http://arquillian.org/blog/tags/tomcat/ By the way- Arquillian is great and I highly recommend it!

Comment: I checked it before. Could not find more than release notes. Proper documentation and examples are missing for arquillian.

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 Options here:

1. Start the test with a runner (or otherwise) who sets up a DB with a Datasource, like in the [answer from phoenix7360](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15524916/15108). But this isn't actually a Unit-Test per definition.
2. Mock the the interaction with the DB with a Mocking framework like [EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org) or [Mockito](http://www.mockito.org).

I'd go with the second option, if you really want to do unit-tests. But your setting isn't exactly that of a Unit-Test more a kind of Integration-Test.

Comment: I understand that first approach is not a pure unit testing. But I am trying to avoid integration stubbing issues right now.