# Insert data using JPA with EJB

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

Suppose I want to do a single data operation on an existing JPA scheme, like for each Entity *Class* create n Entities *Student*. I've added the functionality to handle students, and I want to load them from a CSV file (just an imaginary example). I've prepared the entities and the tables, of course.

Now how can I do this in an EJB scope?

Normally using Spring I would simply write a unit test that uses the  `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` annotation to load the context, where the persistence is initialized. I can't do this in EJB, because I depend on a Java EE container to give me the data-source and `PersistenceContext`.

Comment: Just use Arquillian. See this nearly identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524687/in-container-testing-with-junit/15524916

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPA outside of application containers.  When running within an application container, you're using container-managed entity managers.  You can use JPA in plain JavaSE applications.  In those cases, you want an application-managed entity manager.  Which is using  the javax.persistence.Persistence class to get the EntityManagerFactory (from which you get the EntityManager).

Once you have the entityManager, you can perform the same code.  All you need to do in your tests is ensure you can get at the Persistence class, and you should be all good.